# What is the better aproach when instances of classes needs different functions and variables in js?

Tags: javascript, performance, class, semantics

I have a class called `Gamer` and each instance of it needs a different logic. So `Gamer` *gets a **function** as a paremeter*, but this function needs new attributes (to handle the custom function operation). So what would be better considering **performance/semantics**: Just add these vars with `gamerInstance.new_attr = ...` *or* create a new class for each instance that extends the `Gamer` class? or another thing that I don't know...
Keep in mind that is possible to some instance of `Gamer` to not nedding an extra attribute.
**This function as a parameter is called array.length (> than 10^6) times**

```
class Gamer{
    #name;
    #function;
    constructor(name, function){
        this.#name = name;
        this.#function = function;
        this.number = 0;
    }
    
    static get SOME_CONST() { return 5; }
    //called many times
    manageStrategy(index){ this.#strategy(this, index); }
}

let gamer1 = new Gamer("Gary", (gamer, index) => {
    //do some thing to gamer.number
});
let gamer2 = new Gamer("John", (gamer, index) => {
    //do another thing to gamer.number
});

gamer1.new_attr = 0;
gamer1.new_attr2 = [];

//gamer2 doesn't need extra data to handle its function logic
```

Comment: So why not extend gamer?  `class AwesomeGamer extends Gamer {`

Comment: This is the question. I gues this is not the better approach, 'cause this way I would need to create a class for each instace (can be more than 2, this was just an example)

Comment: It is hard to guess hat is actually different. The approach really is based on what you need to do. Either way you are creating some sort of new instance of rules or classes and using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can couple the function and its properties.

So something like:

```
class GamerLogicA {
    propA;
    propB;
    propC;
    init(){ /*doSomething with propA, propB, propC*/ }
}

class GamerLogicB {
    propD;
    propE;
    init(){ /*doSomething with propD, propE*/ }
}

class Gamer{
    #name;
    #logic;
    constructor(name, logic){
        this.#name = name;
        this.#logic = logic;
        this.#logic.init();
    }
}
```

Then you just inject that instead:

```
let g1 = new Gamer('Gary', new GamerLogicA())
let g2 = new Gamer('John', new GamerLogicB());
```